# Is there a word for the opposing ends of a tangible scale, as there are "obverse" and "reverse" to describe the physical sides of a coin-like object

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

I feel that obverse and reverse are too "Geometric" to properly describe more complex ideas in society where something is not in reality in a completely opposite position in relation to another.

For example we use left wing and right wing politics to simplify politics based upon the seating of Republicans and Royalists in the first French First Republic's Assembly, but today a Conservative is not the opposite of a Reformist- there are stages in between and one cannot state that they are completely separated and are not on the same side.

Am I just over complicating this?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're overcomplicating things or not… because I'm not quite sure what your actual question is. Are you talking about ends/extremes of a spectrum? Or something about the gradualness of spectra? Or is it something else entirely you're looking for a word to describe?

Comment: the "limits" or extremes, or poles

Comment: Based on the question posed in the title of your post, **diametrical opposites** or **antipodes** might fit, as these terms indicate complete opposites.  Based on what you've articulated in the post itself, **contrasts** might be a better fit, as the term merely implies a noticeable difference between people, things, or concepts, without having to be diametrically opposed.  Is this in line with what you're looking for?

Comment: The _opposite ends of the spectrum_ is a (fairly transparent!) metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite ends of a scale could be described as the 'nadir' and the 'apex', but it sounds more like you're describing the opposite ends of a spectrum.